# Pandas : How to return Friday as business day if date is falling on Sunday or Saturday?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return the business day date if my date falls on a Saturday or a Sunday. Following is the code but it seems incomplete. Please suggest.

```
import holidays
import datetime

enter_date = '2020-10-30'
enter_date = pd.to_datetime(enter_date)
before_date = enter_date - datetime.timedelta(days=5)
print(before_date)
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to `import pandas as pd` instead of `import holidays` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a solution that addresses both holidays and weekends.

See if this solves your problem.

## Solution without pandas (for loop & datetime)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import calendar, holidays

#weekday() starts with 0 and ends with 6.
#0 is Mon, 4 is Fri, 5 is Sat, 6 is Sun
#check if weekday is Sat or Sun (> 4)
#if Sat or Sun, subtract a day until you get to Fri
#if day is a holiday, subtract a day until you get to a working day

for enter_date in ['2020-12-09','2020-12-12','2020-12-25', '2020-12-27', '2021-01-18']:
    enter_date = datetime.strptime(enter_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    print ('\nGiven date :', enter_date.date(), 'is a',calendar.day_name[enter_date.weekday()])

    while enter_date in holidays.US() or enter_date.weekday() > 4:
        enter_date = enter_date - timedelta(days=1)

    print ('The business working day is',enter_date.date(), 'and is a', calendar.day_name[enter_date.weekday()])
```

The output of this will be as follows:

```
Given date : 2020-12-09 is a Wednesday
The business working day is 2020-12-09 and is a Wednesday

Given date : 2020-12-12 is a Saturday
The business working day is 2020-12-11 and is a Friday

Given date : 2020-12-25 is a Friday
The business working day is 2020-12-24 and is a Thursday

Given date : 2020-12-27 is a Sunday
The business working day is 2020-12-24 and is a Thursday

Given date : 2021-01-18 is a Monday
The business working day is 2021-01-15 and is a Friday
```

Note here that:

- 12/09/2020 is a Wednesday and no changes were done
- 12/12/2020 is a Saturday and was changed it to 12/11/2020 Friday
- 12/25/2020 is a Friday and a holiday. It was changed to 12/24/2020
  Thursday
- 12/27/2020 is a Sunday, 12/25/2020 is a Friday but a holiday. It was
  changed to 12/24/2020 Thursday
- 01/18/2021 is a Monday and a holiday. It was changed to 01/15/2021
  Friday

## Solution including pandas

Here's a solution that includes pandas:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import calendar, holidays
import pandas as pd

def business_day(enter_date):
    while enter_date in holidays.US() or enter_date.weekday() > 4:
        enter_date = enter_date - timedelta(days=1)

    return enter_date

df = pd.DataFrame({'enter_date':['2020-12-09','2020-12-12','2020-12-25', '2020-12-27','2021-01-18']})
df['enter_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['enter_date'])
df['business_date'] = df['enter_date'].apply(lambda x: business_day(x))
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
  enter_date business_date
0 2020-12-09    2020-12-09
1 2020-12-12    2020-12-11
2 2020-12-25    2020-12-24
3 2020-12-27    2020-12-24
4 2021-01-18    2021-01-15
```

Comment: Let me know if you still need a solution that uses pandas

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek` attribute (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html#pandas-datetimeindex-dayofweek)). It maps each day of the week from Monday to Sunday to `range(7)`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd


saturday = pd.to_datetime('2020-12-12')
sunday = pd.to_datetime('2020-12-13')

def func(date):
    if date.dayofweek == 5: 
        date = date - pd.Timedelta('1 day')  # SATURDAY
    elif date.dayofweek == 6: 
        date = date - pd.Timedelta('2 day')  # SUNDAY
    return date


print(func(saturday))  # 2020-12-11 00:00:00
print(func(sunday))  # 2020-12-11 00:00:00
```